# How do I cast Stream.empty() in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

All the examples I've found use other type information to infer the type of `Stream.empty()`. It seems like there should be syntax to allow me to cast it directly. This example works:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class OptionalBasics {
    static void test(Optional<String> optString) {
        if(optString.isPresent())
            System.out.println(optString.get());
        else
            System.out.println("Nothing inside!");
      }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<String> s = Stream.empty();
        test(s.findFirst());
        test(Stream.of("Epithets").findFirst());
    }
}
/* Output:
Nothing inside!
Epithets
*/
```

But notice that I have to create `s` separately in order to provide type information for `Stream.empty()`. I'd like to just create it in the call to
`test()`, something like this (which doesn't work):

```
test(Stream<String>.empty().findFirst());
```

Is there a syntax for setting the type on the call to `Stream.empty()`?

Comment: Why was it closed even? Hm.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just have the brackets in the wrong spot. Try `Stream.<String> empty().findFirst())`

Comment: Excellent -- thanks so much!